# How to assign dictionary to Struct Class

Tags: swift, dictionary, struct

How to assign dictionary `[String: [Any]] to [FirstModel]?`

A function return `[String:[Any]]` I want to assign this to `[FirstModel]` struct class?

// Reponse Data.

```
{
  "Student" : [
    {
      "code" : "111",
      "id" : "2022-1001",
      "name" : "Kiran",
      "type_id" : "009-110-123"
    }
  ],
  "Subject" : [
    {
      "code" : "111",
      "id" : "2022-2002",
      "name" : "Computer Science",
      "type_id" : "009-110-123"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is Solution which I was written:

```
   func getData(data: RootModel.ResponseFirstModel? = nil) -> [ResultModel]{
        let dict: [String : [RootModel.ArrayModel]] = data?.dictionary ?? [:]
        var resultArray = [ResultModel]()
        var arrayModel = ArrayModel()
        for each in dict {
            arrayModel  = ArrayModel.init(code: each.value.first?.code, id: each.value.first?.id, name: each.value.first?.name, typeId: each.value.first?.typeId)
            resultArray.append(.init(name: each.key, values: [arrayModel]))
        }
        return resultArray
    } 

//Declare ResultModel Class below.
struct ResultModel {
    var name: String?
    var values: [ArrayModel]?
} 

struct ArrayModel {
    var code: String?
    var id: String?
    var name: String?
    var typeId: String?
}
```

Comment: Could you give a sample of `[String:[Any]]` and how it's supposed to be transformed into a `[FirstModel]`? An input/output, and we might help on how to do the middle, but currently, it's hard to tell, since `Any` could be anything...

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, but a `struct` and a `class` are two different things. A `struct` is a `value type`, and a class is a reference type. There's no such thing as a "struct class". That would be like a "fish tree" in biology.

Comment: @Larme I added response json to the question.

Comment: And the target output?

Comment: @Larme I updated the question and solution too,   Is this correct approach? func getData

Comment: What's `RootModel.ResponseFirstModel` & `RootModel.ArrayModel`, just to be sure?

Comment: @Larme the response is huge from api like MetaData inside I given json response.  "Student" is ResponseFirstModel Since Data structure same for Student & Subject then ArrayModel as common for both.

Answer (score 0):

You **can't** assign a `[String: [Any]]` dictionary to a `[FirstModel]` array. They are unrelated types.